# Finding the first Occurrence of a specific value in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells I'm working with, `D2:EU1054`.  Each row contains a set of values `a, b, c, d, e`.

These values don't have a distinct pattern, they can go from A to C back to B.    I need to find a way to highlight  the FIRST occurrence of the value B in each of the rows.

I've been working with conditional formatting, vba code, and formulas to try to figure out how to just get just that that first specific value. Any ideas?  So within the range of `D2:EU1054`, I'd like to highlight the value B the first time it occurs in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub IAmSoBlue()
    For i = 2 To 1054
        For j = 4 To 154
            If Cells(i, j).Value = "B" Then
                Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = 65535
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

You could also use `FIND()` in place of the second loop.